# Can't get updated state from Reducer

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux

I made a login function which updates the `state` in my `reducer` from `false` to `true`. I check this in my `reducer` and my login function. But when I want to check the state in another file it keeps returning `false`.

My login function:

```
axios
    .post('api/user/login', {
        username: this.state.username,
        password: this.state.password
    })
    .then(response => {
        return response;
    })
    .then(json => {
        if (json.data.success) {
            store.dispatch(loginStatus(true));
            console.log('Login: ' + store.getState().loggedIn);
            window.location.assign('/');
        } else {
            alert('Login Failed!');
        }
    })
    .catch(error => {
        alert('An Error Occured!' + error);
        console.log(error);
    });
```

Which returns `true`

My reducer:

```
import { LOGIN_STATUS } from "../constants/action-types";

const initialState = {
    loggedIn: false
};

const rootReducer = (state = initialState, action) => {
    switch (action.type)  {
        case LOGIN_STATUS:
            state.loggedIn=action.payload;
            console.log('Reducer: ' + state.loggedIn);
            return {
                loggedIn: state.loggedIn=action.payload
            };
        default:
            return state;
    }
};

export default rootReducer;
```

Which also returns `true`

But then in my other file:

```
import React from 'react';
import { Redirect, Route } from 'react-router-dom';
import  store from '../store/index';

const privateRouter = ({component: Component, ...rest }) => {

    const isLoggedIn = store.getState().loggedIn;
    console.log('PrivateRoute: ' + isLoggedIn);

    return (
        <Route
            {...rest}
            render={props =>
            isLoggedIn ? (
                <Component {...props} />
            ) : (
                <Redirect to={{ pathname: '/login', state: { from: props.location } }} />
            )}
        />
    )
};

export default privateRouter;
```

it returns `false`. Am I doing something wrong with getting the state? Because in my login function it does return the updated state.

**Update:**

This is my router by the way:

```
   <Provider store={store}>
        <Router>
            <Switch>
                <Route path={'/login'} component={Login}/>
                <Route path={'/register'} component={Register}/>
                <PrivateRoute path={'/'} component={Home}/>
            </Switch>
        </Router>
    </Provider>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems your "privateRouter" function not triggering once the reducer changes the state. You need to trigger privateRouter function in order to get the latest store.
Instead of importing store use "Provider" and "connect" to pass state to components.

https://www.sohamkamani.com/blog/2017/03/31/react-redux-connect-explained/